# Update CentOS from DVD without internet

Tags: centos7, update, dependencies

How to install and update packages from DVD which I mounted? What I do so far is to mount the DVD.

```
#mount -r -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /mnt/DVD
```

So now is there a way to update it automatic all packets or I must do one by one? For example:

```
yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=DVD install ....
```

UPDATE: This is content of /etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo

```
[DVDRepo]
name=Local DVD Repository
baseurl=file:///mnt/DVD
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first you have to create a repo file for your new repo (the dvd)
For example a file called /etc/yum.repos.d/dvd.repo

```
[dvd]
name=Local DVD Repository
baseurl=file:///mnt/DVD
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

Then you should disable your other repos and update, and you'll be able to run a yum update from there.

Comment: Sorry for my late comment and thanks for your answer. I have updated my question with content of the repo file. When I run `yum update` I got this: `Loaded plugins: fastestmirror` and `file:///mnt/DVD/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for DVDRepo: Damaged repomd.xml file`

Comment: my bad I used my knowledge about old RedHat dvd to write the answer, I've tried with a new CentOS 7 DVD and updated my answer.

Comment: I have name `name=Local DVD Repository`

Comment: ah right, I will edit my answer.

Comment: So you mean that I must remove `gpgcheck=1` from my file?

Comment: no you should keep it, I will edit again

Comment: Yes, that's the content of my file. Yet, now when I do `yum update` I got the error: `Loaded plugins: fastestmirror` and `file:///mnt/DVD/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for DVDRepo: Damaged repomd.xml file`

Comment: which version of CentOS and what DVD file do you have ?

Comment: `CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)` and DVD inserted is `Everything.iso` which contain rpm's which I want to install/update

Comment: okay I used the regular DVD Iso, let me time to download the everything iso and I'll update

Comment: Okay the iso has exactly the same behaviour as the other one, are you sure your iso is valid ? Did you md5 it ?
Also could you list it's content ? it should have a repodata directory in the /mnt/DVD once mounted.

Comment: I can navigate to the dvd. Also I can `ls` it. Also I can see and go in directory `repodata` ... But I don't know exactly what you mean by `Did you md5 it ?` How can I do this?

Comment: the repodata is where the database of packages is stored, so that's what yum is trying to gather to offer you the list of packages to install. In your case it seems that dir is corrupted. md5 is a checksum, it's used to make sure that your dvd file is not corrupted while transfered over networks. the provider of the iso gives you what he gets being sure it's not corrupted and you can verify yours by typing `md5sum Everything.iso`
the problem with your iso is that we can't really know which version it is, so it's hard to find the appropriate md5sum to compare to.

Comment: is there a specific need for using that iso and not the internet repository ?

you might try a `yum  clean all` and then `yum makecache` again

Comment: `is there a specific need for using that iso and not the internet repository ?` Yes, because the machine doesn't have internet...

Comment: okay, then maybe you should try re-downloading this iso again, as it might be corrupted.

Comment: CentOS 7.2 is out already! It's not really "updating" if you're 18 months behind!

Comment: Thank's but is not the question the version. I mean since I use 7 and going this hard way to update it.. may be I have some reasons for that.

Comment: what did you change ?